# proving the convergence of a monotone decreasing sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let {$a_k$}$_{k=1 \to \infty}$ be a sequence of real numbers which satisfies the condition

$ \lvert a_{k+1}-a_k \rvert \le \frac{1}{2}\lvert a_k - a_{k-1}\rvert$ for all $k\ge2$. Show that {$a_k$} converges.

We know that if $n<m$ then $a_n-a_m = \sum_{k=n}^{m-1} (a_k-a_{k-1})$ so I know $a_n-a_m = (a_n - a_{n-1})+ (a_{n+1}-a_n) + (a_{n+2}-a_{n+1})+...+(a_{m-1}-a_m)$

so everything cancels out but $a_n-a_m$

$\lvert a_{k+1}-a_k \rvert \le \frac{1}{2}\lvert a_k-a_{k-1}\rvert \le \frac{1}{4}\lvert a_{k-1}-a_{k-2} \rvert \le \frac{1}{8}\lvert a_{k-2}-a_{k-3}\rvert$

But now I'm lost how to connect this to proving the convergence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using induction we can prove that $|a_{k+1}-a_k|\le\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}|a_2-a_1|$, then, if $n$ and $m$ are integers with $n>m>0$ we have, from triangle inequality
$$|a_n-a_m|\le\sum_{j=1}^{n-m}|a_{n-j+1}-a_{n-j}|\le \sum_{j=1}^{n-m}\frac{1}{2^j}|a_{m+1}-a_m|\le\sum_{j=1}^{n-m}\frac{1}{2^{m+j-1}}|a_{2}-a_1|\tag{1}$$
Now, since $m-1<m\le(1+1)^{m-1}=2^{m-1}$ (from Bernoulli's inequality), we have $$\sum_{j=1}^{n-m}\frac{1}{2^{m+j-1}}|a_{2}-a_1|<\frac{|a_2-a_1|}{2^{m-1}}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^j}=\frac{|a_2-a_1|}{2^{m-1}}<\frac{|a_2-a_1|}{m-1}\tag{2}$$

For $\varepsilon >0$ let $N_{\varepsilon}$ an integer greater that $\frac{|a_2-a_1|}{\varepsilon}+1$, from ($1$) and ($2$) we have
$$n>m\ge N_{\varepsilon}\quad\implies\quad |a_n-a_m|<\varepsilon$$